# In a proof of the Sherman-Morrison formula why does $(I+wv^T)^{-1}=I-\frac{wv^T}{1+v^Tw}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand the alternate proof of the formula $(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - {A^{-1}uv^T A^{-1} \over 1 + v^T A^{-1}u}$ found on [wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula#Alternative_verification).

The closest I can find on stack exchange is the [use](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154966/sherman-morrison-formula-to-determine-inverse-of-3-times-3-matrix?rq=1) of the identity but not its proof.
Does someone know how $$(I+wv^T)^{-1}=I-\frac{wv^T}{1+v^Tw} \tag{1}$$ is easily proven? I don't see it.

---

You can mark the question as duplicate if you want but all the proofs are proving the Sherman-Morrison formula, not the intermediate identity given in (1). The two are similar as I see now that someone proved it, but it still is worth showing explicitely how to prove the identity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of the Sherman-Morrison Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705671/proof-of-the-sherman-morrison-formula)

Comment: The 'proof' on the wiki page is a verification to be precise. Of course, multiplying two matrices to get the identity matrix proves that the matrices are inverses of each other. However, we can 'derive' the result in a different manner as I show in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2203697/321264) answer.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Does there ever exist a situation where $AB=I$ but $BA\ne I$?

Comment: When $A$ and $B$ are not square matrices, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can solve the equation $(I+ wv^T) x = y$ directly to obtain $x$:

Suppose $(I+ wv^T) x = x + w v^T x = y$.

Then $v^T x + v^T w v^T x = (1+ v^T w) (v^T x) = v^Ty$, or 
$v^T x = {v^Ty \over 1 + v^T w}$.

Hence the first equation can be written as
$x + {wv^Ty \over 1 + v^T w} = y$ or
$x = (I-{wv^T \over 1 + v^T w} ) y$.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to recognize that $v^Tw$ is a scalar.
\begin{align}&(I+wv^T) \left(I-\frac{wv^T}{1+v^Tw} \right)\\&=
I+wv^T-\frac{wv^T}{1+v^Tw}-\frac{wv^Twv^T}{1+v^Tw} \\&=
I+wv^T-\left (\frac{wv^T}{1+v^Tw}+\frac{wv^Twv^T}{1+v^Tw}\right ) \\&=
I+wv^T-\frac{w(1+v^Tw)v^T}{1+v^Tw}\\&=
I+wv^T-wv^T \\&=I
\end{align}